# Implement wrapper/global AJAX request handler?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

In Angular.js Is it possible to implement a wrapper that will execute whenever a AJAX post request is made and gets a 401 HTTP response?

My web app makes dozens of RESTful requests to the server. If their login session expires the server returns a HTTP 401 response. Now, that doesn't trigger the 'fail' function of the post request (annoyingly). But even if it did, I don't want to now edit dozens of RESTful requests functions and have them check if the error response == 401 then refresh the page (to force the user to re-login).

I just want to implement a POST wrapper that will affect all current and future requests. Is this possible?

Comment: In this case we have to write interceptors. Which angular version you are using?

Comment: @ShoaibKonnur I'm using version 1.5.11

Comment: As recommended by @ShoaibKonnur, you can use the interceptors in angularjs. This link will help https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors